# What is "the client for a session" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, session, client

What exactly does the MySQL documentation mean when it says "the client for a session"?

Is it maybe each one of the users for a database?

For example, when it says "A temporary table is only available and accessible to the client that creates it...". Does that mean that the table is only available for the MySQL user who created it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A session is a single connection, corresponding to one thread in the MySQL Server, which can be viewed in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

There are several things that are scoped to the session:

- Session variables
- Temporary tables
- Transactions
- Last insert id generated for an auto-increment column

When the documentation says the temporary table is accessible only to the client that creates it, that means only in the same connection. There may be other connections for the same MySQL user, but each connection is a different session.

Comment: What do you mean by query history? If you're talking about interactive recall of previous queries, that's not tied to the session, it's internal to the `mysql` CLI client.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema-events-statements-history-table.html

Comment: Actually, it's a good point, because the PS statement history has a per-session retention, but it's not scoped to the session, because any clients can read that PS table. I'll remove that item from the list.

Comment: Can I then enter the same connection from different machines? I guess no, rigth.

Comment: No, each connection is unique. It sounds like temporary tables are not what you need for whatever task you're doing.